# Cannot convert value of type 'UIHostingController<AnyView>' to closure result type 'UIHostingController<Page>'

Tags: swiftui

I'm making a PageView implementation with SwiftUI according to the [Interacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) tutorial.

And, particularly, there is such code:

```
struct PageView<Page: View>: View {
  var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<Page>]
  @State var currentPage = 0

  init(_ views: [Page]) {
      self.viewControllers = views.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
  }

  var body: some View {
    PageViewController(controllers: viewControllers, currentPage: $currentPage)
  }
}
```

The View may be called in a simple way:

```
PageView([FirstView(), SecondView()])
```

I want to make nice paddings around the page views, so I can call this view in following manner:

```
PageView([AnyView(FirstView().padding()), AnyView(SecondView().padding()])
```

All is good, but I have to repeat every time the .padding() and wrapping in the AnyView in caller method. However, when I try to move this code to the init method, I'm trapped in the error, I can't get around:

```
  init(_ views: [Page]) {
      self.viewControllers = views.map { UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView($0.padding())) }
  }
```

which is reported as **Cannot convert value of type 'UIHostingController<AnyView>' to closure result type 'UIHostingController<Page>'**

Any hint how to address it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest would be to add padding

```
  var body: some View {
    PageViewController(controllers: viewControllers, currentPage: $currentPage)
        .padding()     // << here !!
  }
```

but if you want to make those `AnyView`s in `init`, then change declaration of member as

```
  var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<AnyView>]    // << here !!
```

Comment: Thanks, @Asperi, the first solution doesn't work, as I want to have paddings between individual views in PageControl, thus scrolling will show separators between the pages.
However the second one - works.
I'm really confused now, as I'm sure I tried it and didn't succeed, there was another compile message, may be XCode restart helped, or whatever.